# How to capture two regex

Tags: grep, regular-expression, string, search

In this command, I want to extract strings that are like *.com or *.net, where * is not a dot.
I wrote this:

```
grep -P -E '^[^.]+\.com$ |^[^.]+\.net$' example.csv
```

I get this error:

```
grep: conflicting matchers specified
```

Can you clarify?

Comment: This error just means that `-E` (for extended regular expression) and `-P` (Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE)) options are exclusive and cannot be used both at same time. Choose only one. This is not a regexp error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use both PCRE (`-P`) and Extended Regular Expressions (`-E`) at the same time.  In this case, it seems as if you don't use PCRE expressions at all, so you could just drop the `-P`. You also can't expect to match a space after `$`.

Combining most of the expression into a shorter one:

```
grep -E '^[^.]+\.(com|net)$'
```

Or,

```
grep -E -x '[^.]+\.(com|net)'
```

The `-x` option will cause `grep` to only match complete lines.

The expression matches a non-zero number of non-dot characters, followed by a dot and then either `net` or `com`.